# A sum of images

Tags: visual, knowledge

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]

---

### 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = ?

The answer can be given as either an image or a description of the image.

Comment: it's not '36' perchance?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Haha no, the numbers represent the images in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each image refers to

> a band that has a number in its name:
>
>  1. [Alabama **3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama_3)
>  2. [**22** Jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_Jacks) (per @WeslySitu)
>  3. [Jackson **5**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jackson_5)
>  4. [Matchbox **20**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_Twenty).
>  5. [**21** Pilots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_One_Pilots)
>  6. [**30** Seconds to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Seconds_to_Mars)
>  7. [Sum **41**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_41)
>  8. [UB**40**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UB40) *(this is the coat of arms of the **University of Barcelona**)* (per @WesleySitu)

The sum of numbers 1 to 8 is

> **182**. This means that the answer is the band [Blink 182](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink-182), and an appropriate image for the solution might be:
>
>   [image]

Comment: I just put 6 and 7 in their right place (they was inverted)

Comment: I added a bit more to this. Still can't get an answer though

Comment: barcelona has a song called "drop everything". maybe the result is 0 :D

Comment: Coincidentally, there is a band called Alabama 3 as well. (It doesn't change your answer though).

Comment: there's Barcelona FC 2016

Comment: I don't think it is the answer for #8, but (U)niversity of (B)arcelona = UB40?

Comment: apparently there was a us band named barcelona before the current indie rock band. they had some songs with numbers. e.g. "1/2". one of their albums is called  ZeRo-oNe-INFINITY.

Comment: nvm, @APrough is probably right.

Comment: Maybe Alabama represents number "22"? It was 22th state that joined USA.

Comment: The only issue I have with my suggestion is all other numbers were in order, so I want to say it should be > 41.  Plus, can't find a band with 164 in the name.

Comment: Maybe an album with that number in it...

Comment: Every other answer is a band with a number.  I would hope that the OP would not throw us that far off track.  There should be a theme, right?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the addition result is 182.  Which leaves 58 unaccounted for so far.

Comment: Well, there is in fact a band called "58". But I have no clue whatsoever what they might have to do with barcelona. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/58_(band)

Comment: Unit 187 for #8?  Which gives a rather famous band...

Comment: Good point. Might be the correct answer. In case it is,  here's a pic:  https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/73121155/311thumb2_400x400.jpg

Comment: If you swap 2 with "22 Jacks" and 8 with "UB40" (@LiamH, @APrough), we get the +58 we need for rot13 oyvax 182 :)

Comment: @WesleySitu - Wesley, you may have it.  That solution fits all of the clues and comes up with one of the (most likely) solutions.

Comment: Well done everyone! The only thing I'm not happy with yet is the final image, but that's okay. Once I get home I'll add the picture I had in mind and accept the answer.

Comment: Yay :) that was quite the journey...

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to add a separate answer because its a long shot. So I don't want to ruin the other answer.

Maybe its:

> an image of the 212 area of NYC
>
>  1. Alabama, have an album called  **16** biggest hits
>
>  2. This could be an image of Jack Black. Tenacious D have a song called **39**
>
>  3. Michael Jackson - Jackson **5**
>
>  4. Matchbox **20**
>
>  5. **Twenty One** pilots
>
>  6. **30** seconds to mars
>
>  7. Sum **41**
>
>  8. UB.**40**
>
>  The total sum here is **212**, which is the debut single by Azelia Banks. It seems a Long shot with 1 and 2 I know!

Comment: Nice try, but not the right answer

Comment: Ah well, worth a try! Good puzzle!