# 4 sums of flags (Part 2)

Tags: visual, knowledge, flags

*The previous 'Sum of' puzzles can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/a-sum-of-images) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32859/4-sums-of-flags)*

---

[image: Here we go again...] + [image: Look at this flag!] = [image: Oh boy! A flag!]  
[image: You guessed it... Flag!] + [image: Hmmm this flag looks a bit weird] = [image: Please don't flag this question]  
[image: Daaaaaaamn! Back at it again with the flags!] + [image: You can't even see the left side of this flag. It's there though. It's white.] = [image: Wow, this flag looks a lot like that other one!]  
[image: Almost there...] + [image: Question mark incoming!] = ?

Which flag should replace the question mark?

---

*Hint:*

> Hmmm, some of those country names are pretty long. If only we could do something about that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The countries are:

> China + Belgium = Latvia
>  Costa Rica + Canada = Russia
>  Portugal + Madagascar = Thailand
>  Slovenia + Brasil  = ?

According to the hint, we should use abbreviations of the countries, though. Let's use the top level domains:

> `cn + be = lv`
>  `cr + ca = ru`
>  `pt + mg = th`
>  `si + br = ?`

There doesn't seem to be a way of making these equations valid sums by converting bases or enumerating letters, but we can turn these abbreviations to numbers by ...

> ... considering them as symbols of chemical elements, whose atomic numbers we use:
>
>  Copernicum (112) + Beryllium (4) = Livermonium (116)
>  Chromium (24) + Calcium (20) = Ruthenium (44)
>  Platinum (78) + Magnesium (12) = Thorium (90)
>  Silicon (14) + Bromine (35) = Indium (49)

So the flag that should replace the question mark is ...

> ... the flag of a country whose TLD is `in`:
>
>    [image: Flag of India]

Comment: Well done! I have stared at the numbers for the last half an hour trying to obtain some formula to make them work.

Comment: Correct! Well done :)

Comment: omg I totally failed on the belgium flag. i'm so ashamed >.<

Comment: wait sv != si. (slovenia->silicon)

Comment: .sv is El Salvador, .si is Slovenia

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had it right when finding the elements obviously, but not when writing the answer. I'll fix it.