# I've lost contact with our agent, and only have this short message

Tags: cipher

Our best agent is tracking down a murder/blackmail case.  He was periodically checking in with us, but we suddenly lost contact.  Here is his last transmission:

> F6AC3CF7C2CE1BE2CD3CF5FE1F2CD4AC3B2CD3F8CA2CD3BE9CD2B5

I cannot decode it.  It's clearly a hexadecimal string, but what do I know ... please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message is ...

> ... only superficially a hexadecimal string. The string follows a pattern: One or two letters are followed by a single digit. The letter combinations that occur in the message are:
>
>   B, C, F, AC, BE, CA, CD, CE, CF, FE

You can reformat this ...

> ... by lowercasing the second letter and you see that these are symbols of chemical elements, namely:
>
>  **B** Boron (5)
>  **C** Carbon (6)
>  **F** Fluorine (9)
>  **Ac** Actinium (89)
>  **Be** Beryllium (4)
>  **Ca** Calcium (20)
>  **Cd** Cadmium (48)
>  **Ce** Cerium (58)
>  **Cf** Californium (98)
>  **Fe** Iron (26)

Usually, in such cases ...

> ... the atomic number is used, but here the number after each symbol just specifies the letter to take from the element's name. The message begins with
>
>   F6 Ac3 Cf7
>
>  which decodes to the 6th letter of Fluor**I**ne, the 3rd letter of Ac**T**inium, the 7th letter of Califo**R**nium and so on.

The message reads:

> I traced film to dead man.

Comment: Well done.  And I thought this one would be hard.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, it wasn't easy without anything to go by except the message itself and I was about to give up. But when I saw the pattern, it clicked. I was probably just in the right frame of mind, because I've used that pattern in [another answer recently](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33535/4-sums-of-flags-part-2/33654#33654).

Comment: Theree are two hints in there, which I think I'll reduce to zero next time.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham I would recommend leaving the second sentence unchanged. People are generally not fond of puzzles where there is a string of characters without any indication of how to decipher them. This one gives just enough guidance as it is.

Comment: @GordonK Thanks, I agree with you.  There needs to be something to chew on.